# Converting tuple occurences to string in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column that has the occasional tuple inserted into it. I would like to join all of these tuples into one string separated by `','`.

EX

```
Data      People
 A        XYZ
 B        ABX,LMN
 C       ('OPP', 'GGG')
 D        OAR
```

I am only trying to 'target' the tuple here and convert it to a string giving the following dataframe:

```
Data      People
 A        XYZ
 B        ABX,LMN
 C        OPP,GGG
 D        OAR
```

`df['People'] = df['People'].apply(','.join)`

I tried this, but it ends up inserting commas in between every character in all of the 'OK' strings.

Comment: I'd look into first fixing this upstream -- what monstrosity of a process causes data to be written like this? Fix that first. No need for hacky solutions, especially when dealing with mixed object columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must, you can do something like below.

```
df['People'] = df['People'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x) if isinstance(x,tuple) else x)
```

Output:

```
  Data  People
0   A   XYZ
1   B   ABX, LMN
2   C   OPP, GGG
3   D   QAR
```

Comment: This gives a type error `'type' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Probably better to have `', '.join(x)` to deal with tuples with any number of elements

Comment: Also probably better to use ```', '.join(str(x))``` in case any of the elements is an integer

Comment: @TPereira, that will separate out each character in a string.

Comment: @MaxB, have you used `tuple` as a variable name in your script?

Answer (score 1):

This works may not be the most elegant solution:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': ['AA', 'ABC, LMN', ('XYZ', 'PQR'), 'OLA']})

# Output

    A   B
0   1   AA
1   2   ABC, LMN
2   3   (XYZ, PQR)
3   4   OLA
```

```py
df['B'].apply(lambda x: ','.join([val for val in x]) if isinstance(x, tuple) else x)

# Output

0          AA
1    ABC, LMN
2     XYZ,PQR
3         OLA
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You may avoid `apply` by using `map` to create mask `True` on `tuple`. Use this mask to slice on rows having tuple and use `str.join` directly on it.

```
m = df.People.map(type).eq(tuple)
df.loc[m, 'People'] = df.loc[m, 'People'].str.join(',')


Out[2206]:
  Data   People
0    A      XYZ
1    B  ABX,LMN
2    C  OPP,GGG
3    D      OAR
```